# Generating a "flare" effect in Graphics3D?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

I'm attempting to indicate that there is a point-source of light at some position in a Graphics3D-generated image.  Is there any built-in tool to do this?  My patch-work solution thus far has been to imagine a sphere of radius $r$ centered at that point, and to generate a large set of diameter-length chords inside of the sphere.  Surely there must be a better way that doesn't involve creating so many line or cylinder primitives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not very pretty, but:

```
Graphics3D[{
  Gray,
  Specularity[3, 5],
  Sphere[],
  Cuboid[{-10, -10, -2}, {10, 10, -1}],

  { (* light *)
   White,
   EdgeForm[None],
   Glow[Yellow],
   Opacity[0.5],
   Scale[
    Translate[
     PolyhedronData["GreatStellatedDodecahedron", "Faces"], 
     {2, 2, 10}],
    3]
   }
  },
 Lighting -> {{"Point", Yellow, {2, 2, 10}},
   {"Directional", White, {0, 0, 20}}},
 Boxed -> False,
 Background -> Gray
 ]
```

[image: scene]

Comment: I like it!  Is there an easy way for me to generate these polytope's at a list of 3D coordinates?

Comment: @user, try `PolyhedronData["GreatStellatedDodecahedron", "VertexCoordinates"]`. See the docs for more details.

Comment: @J.M. That doesn't quite seem to work?  Can I do something like: Graphics3D[{Table[Translate[PolyhedronData["Icosahedron"],CoordinateList[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[CoordinateList]}]}]?

Comment: @user, then I don't understand what you want. You ask for something that generates coordinates, I showed you a command that generates a pile of coordinates, and now you want a picture. What now?

Comment: @J.M. Sorry, I think I'm not being very clear on my end.  I meant, I'd like to position some number $N$ of these polytopes in 3-space at coordinates I specify with a list.  I think you thought I was asking for the coordinates of the polytope vertices.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @user, Ah, then you can do something like `Map[Translate[(* some polyhedron *), #] &, CoordinateList]`.

Comment: @J.M. That's very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 16):

Maybe using some `Line`s to simulate a *flare star*:

```
flarerays = Normalize /@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {500, 3}];

Graphics3D[{
  White, Specularity[.1, 10], Sphere[],
  Opacity[.1],
  Orange,
  Line[{{1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 2} + 10 #}] & /@ flarerays,
  Blue,
  Line[{{-1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1} + 10 #}] & /@ flarerays
  },
 Lighting -> {
   {"Point", Orange, {1, 1, 2}},
   {"Point", Blue, {-1, 1, -1}}
   },
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 3}},
 Background -> Black]
```

[image: flare stars]

Comment: Pretty! So a +1 ...

Comment: @cormullion Thanks :) I used similar flaring thing as splash screen picture for some of my packages :)

Comment: Might be cheaper to use `flarerays = Normalize /@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {500, 3}]`

Comment: @J.M. Yes indeed! Have added to the code. Thanks :)

Comment: nice+1       2, so space               !

Comment: @HyperGroups Thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

Also not very pretty:

```
lights = {{"Point", Green, {5, 0, 0}}, {"Point", Red, {0, -5, 0}}};
indicators = Text[Style["*", 50, Bold, #2], #3] & @@@ lights;

Graphics3D[{Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 3], indicators}, Lighting -> lights]
```

[image]

Comment: Much better http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-y8amuWKvhek/T5ekiJmmXpI/AAAAAAAAAUs/1BzANow0bk0/s1600/Road+to+Pixar+Logo.jpg :)

Comment: "Also not very pretty", actually I disagree, and its fantastic to learn how to do this.